# How Php To Json converted?

Tags: php, json

We can convert php code how to json format?
I may have not accurately PHP coding I am beginner to learn about it because I'm new . I'll integrated into Android application.
I also draw pictures about how the information ?

for example, I want to do something like this: http://mikepenz.com/android/unsplash/pictures

```
<?php
// don't forget to change 'username' to your actual tumblr name
$request = 'http://walltumbler.tumblr.com/api/read/json';
$ci = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$input = curl_exec($ci);
// Tumblr JSON doesn't come in standard form, some str replace needed
$input = str_replace('var tumblr_api_read = ','',$input);
$input = str_replace(';','',$input);
// parameter 'true' is necessary for output as PHP array
$value = json_decode($input, true);
$content =  $value['posts'];
// the number of items you want to display
$item = 98988;
// Tumblr provides various photo size, this case will choose the 75x75 square one
$type = 'photo-url-1280';


?>
{
    "limit": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 2442,
    "total": 2442,
    "data": [

<?php

for ($i=0;$i<=$item;$i++) {
    if ($content[$i]['type'] == 'photo') {
        echo '
          {
            "id": '.$i.';
            "author": "Paul Jarvis",
            "image_src": "' . $content[$i][$type] . '",
            "color": "#7F7873",
            "date": "2015-01-21 19:20:00",
            "modified_date": "2014-09-01 22:36:53",
            "width": 2500,
            "height": 1667,
            "ratio": 1.4997000694275,
            "featured": 1,
            "temp_id": 1
        }';
      $string = rtrim($item, ', ');
    }
}
?>
]}
```

Comment: Try english next time. `json_encode()` by the way

Comment: Take a look below, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

```
<?php

$request = 'http://walltumbler.tumblr.com/api/read/json';
$ci = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$input = curl_exec($ci);
$input = str_replace('var tumblr_api_read = ','',$input);
$input = str_replace(';','',$input);
$value = json_decode($input, true);
$content =  $value['posts'];
$item = 98988;
$type = 'photo-url-1280';

$photos_array = array();

for ($i=0;$i<=$item;$i++) {
    if ($content[$i]['type'] == 'photo') {
        $photos_array[] = array(
            'id' => $i,
            'author' => 'Paul Jarvis',
            // Continue with all your values...
        );
    }
}

$json_data = array(
    'limit'  => null,
    'offset' => 0,
    'count'  => 2442,
    'total'  => 2442,
    'data'   => $photos_array
);

// Then use json_encode to get your json data...

echo json_encode( $json_data );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you should do and why you should do it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: How do I find the way of the image height and width with php?

Comment: Use $image = getimagesize(_path_to_your_image_); It will return an array with 7 elements. The first is width and second is height. $image[0] is width $image[1] is height [View PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)